# Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache) with Wordpress, Microsoft Azure and IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis, wordpress, azure

I'm starting experience very annoying downtimes with my Wordpress installation hosted in a shared environment in Microsoft Azure PAAS, where PHP is executed under IIS.

First of all I tried to optimize plugins and memory consumptions, which is always a good thing to do anyway. But problems persist, so I started digging further. But I must say I'm not very experienced in Windows and IIS at first place.

Said that, I see lot of those lines in the log. They are absolutely obscure to me and even Google was not able to provide me further details.

```
[11-Nov-2014 00:36:10 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache): 212 in Unknown on line 0
[11-Nov-2014 00:59:42 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache): 212 in Unknown on line 0
[11-Nov-2014 01:11:47 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache): 212 in Unknown on line 0
[11-Nov-2014 01:15:07 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache): 212 in Unknown on line 0
```

would be really nice to know at least...what's going on. Could be those errors the source of my performance problems?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I am experiencing the same issue with an Azure Website which runs on IIS

Comment: not really. At the end of the dat I ended up switching to Digital Ocean

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is **WinCache** extension, existed some problems reported with the use of this extension  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58985, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59352 and others.

You can try to disable from your code:

```
ini_set('wincache.fcenabled','0');
```

Also check if exists some plugin that is using this extension.

I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Failure in PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(Wincache): 212 in Unknown on line 0
```

is a `FATAL_FILEMAP_CREATEFILEMAP`  error.  This happens when WinCache is unable to create the shared memory map for one of its caches (Opcode, File, User, or Session).  This can happen if the page file is full, and you've specified a large cache size.  This can also happen if you've specified a file path that is inaccessible or does not exist in either `session.save_path` or `wincache.filemapdir`.

Source: I'm the current owner of WinCache.